# How to make Html page fit in mobile devices

Tags: html, css

Im currently working on my school projects. I want my Html page to fit in mobile devices. i have a navbar in the page.

Comment: You might have at look at the MDN page for [responsive design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet, and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Comment: Make sure you are adding this meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`